# Bind a specific git submodule branch to a specific main repo branch

Tags: git

I am trying to automate a recurring workplace scenario.

I have a repo `myRepo` which contains a submodule `mySub`. I create a new branch for `myRepo` called `myRepoBranch` and also a new branch for `mySub` called `mySubBranch`. I commit changes in both branches and submit them for a pull request.

Issues arise where code in `myRepoBranch` directly depends on code in `mySubBranch`. If after submitting my pull request I checkout master and run `git pull` and `git submodule update`, `mySub` will no longer point to `mySubBranch`. This behaviour is expected and is perfectly fine for master. But if I need to checkout `myRepoBranch` again, I will also have to manually checkout `mySubBranch` for the submodule.

Is there a way to automate this manual submodule checkout? Is it possible to bind a specific submodule branch to a specific main repo branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/8155

Answer (score 0):

In git 1.8.2+ `git submodule add -b branch_name URL_to_Git_repo optional_directory_rename`

git 2.10+ added a great feature.

> The name of the branch is recorded as submodule..branch in
>   .gitmodules for update --remote. A special value of . is used to
>   indicate that the name of the branch in the submodule should be the
>   same name as the current branch in the current repository.

```
git submodule add -b . URL_to_Git_repo optional_directory_rename

# update your submodule
git submodule update --remote
```

[How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Watch out for HTML characters, the text got rendered as `submodule..branch` rather than `submodule.<branch>.branch` as StackOverflow markdown thinks `<branch>` is a bogus HTML directive and strips it from the generated result...